# How to add multiple font files for the same custom font in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, custom-font

I am trying to add a custom font in a Xamarin forms application. The font(Eg: Lato) has been downloaded from "google fonts" and has different files for Bold and Italic. How do I register multiple font files for the same font family in Xamarin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just need  to rename them like xxx-Bold.ttf and xxx-Italic.ttf .And about the usage of custom font you can check https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Hi Lucas. Thank you for your reply. But with this approach I will have to change the font family to set bold or italics etc right? I need to set the font family as, say for example 'Lato' and change set bold or italics by setting the font attributes. In CSS I could have registered multiple font files for a single font family by using the @font-face rule.

Comment: Yes , you could change the font family to set bold or italics etc